# Synonym for catching up

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm looking for a word to describe being glad that you were able to catch up with something promptly.

As in:

> I am happy for the Covid lockdown, because I was able to **just catch up** with this other thing I wanted to do.

Another example for a single word synonym:

> I was given some extra time, and therefore was able to ___ get that done.

I want to explain that **gladly I was able to make it/catch up with it right at the last minute.**

It doesn't have to be one word, but I would prefer it...

Comment: Why have you rejected *catch up*?

Comment: Do you need anything at all in "I was given some extra time, and therefore was able to get that done."? it seems to work just fine as it is.

Comment: In my native language, there is a word which perfectly describes what I want say. Catch up is not that bad I guess but I was hoping for something "stronger", something that would give away the sense that I am glad that I was able to catch up. Like a "I barely made it, THANK GOD!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also consider "up to speed" which is very similar to "catch up" but without the negative connotation you mentioned in the response comment.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. `I was given some extra time, and therefore was able to get up to speed and get that done.` I guess at the end of the day "catch up with" and "get up to speed" are not that different....

Comment: I agree with you, both use space-movement as a reference but when you say "catch up" it sounds like you fell behind.and you had to exert that extra effort and who know you could fall behind again later. I think that's why it feels like there's some negative connotation to it. On the other hand "up to speed" sounds like you were are a different speed now you are up to the speed at which you are supposed to be since speed itself mean you are constantly in motion and now at the right speed so you would be making progress as planned now that you are all "caught up" :P

Answer (score 0):

I have little time before breakfast but can just manage to answer your question with this brief sentence.

Comment: I want to change this `I have little time before breakfast but can just manage to answer your question with this brief sentence.` To this `I had little time before breakfast but (GLADLY JUST MANAGED) to answer your question with this brief sentence.`

Comment: @Alexandros I feel happy with that. Some respondents might advice commas either side of gladly but I think it unnecessary here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, what you need is the expression "under the wire," as in "Luckily, I got it done under the wire."

Check out this link:
[under the wire](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/under+the+wire)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :))) I checked out the link. `Just in the nick of time; at the last moment.` is kind of what I was looking for but for some reason it just doesn't give exactly the meaning I was going for either. 